# Deliver fetchmail messages to two different MDA's

Tags: spamassassin, procmail, email

I'm running `fetchmail` on a AntiSpam server to get messages on user's junk folder to feed SpamAssassin bayesian filtering. It's been running nicely with the `-m` option in `fetchmail` to deliver the messages to SpamAssassin `sa-learn` tool.

But I would like to start testing Bogofilter and feed the Bogofilter database accordingly. But to do this `fetchmail` should deliver the messages to SpamAssassin and Bogofilter, and using the `-m` was a no go.

There's a way to achive this with `fetchmail`? I've considered some extra MDA's like `procmail` or `maildrop`, but I'm not sure if it's really necessary or if it will do the work.

EDIT: My actual `fetchmail` command to fetch messages from the mail server:

```
echo "poll $mailserver proto IMAP user $domain\\$user\\$mailbox pass $passwd ssl" \
| fetchmail -a -n -p IMAP --folder "$junkfolder" -f - -m '/usr/local/bin/sa-learn \
-C /usr/mailcleaner/etc/mailscanner/spam.assassin.prefs.conf --spam'
```

EDIT: I GOT IT! Answering my own question...

Comment: How about write a wrapper (ba)sh script that take `stdin` and pass that `stdin` to both bogofilter and spamassasin?

Comment: It could be an option, but I should deliver mails coming from fetchmail to some place. Any ideia?

Comment: Umm sorry. I don't familiar with fetchmail :D. What do you mean *deliver email to some place*? Via SMTP/LDA/MDA?

Comment: Yep. LDA, MDA, whatever. If nothing is specified, fetchmail delivers to anything running on port 25. I'm using sa-learn as the MDA. I've updated the question with the command line.

Comment: I think I got it using maildrop... Doing some tests now.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to do if you use Procmail as the LDA.  Here is a Procmail recipe to pass the message to two different scripts, then deliver it to SPAM.  (Deliver to `/dev/null` instead if you don't want to keep it; or equivalently, remove the `c` flag from the last recipe.)

```
# I doubt this is necessary, but since you were using an explicit path name...
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

:0c
| sa-learn -C /usr/mailcleaner/etc/mailscanner/spam.assassin.prefs.conf --spam

:0c
| bogofilter

:0
SPAM/
```

It's not hard to write a shell script which performs the same actions, but Procmail does a bunch of things to make sure email is not lost or delivered insecurely, so it's nice as a wrapper.

Comment: Obviously, you could do the same thing with Maildrop as well.  I'm not familiar enough with Maildrop to actually post a solution.